# Konica Minolta 654e - Change Email Subject on Scanned Emails

Tags: email, network-printer, multi-function-printer

I was able to find this video for changing the email-subject on scanned emails for a Konica Minolta 654e printer:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGUF2NyxJX0

However, the video requires physical access to the printer (using the printer's touch-screen interface).

I need to accomplish this same task via the Printer's **web interface**.

From the web interface, I've added what I want the subject of emails to be here:

[image]

As you can see, I specified that I want the subject to just be "Scanned Document" and the screenshot above indicates that it is the "Email Default". However, the printer continues to specify the printer's default email-subject on scanned document, which is: "Message from KM_654e".

In the video I linked above, he was able to change the default email-subject to his own custom entry, how can I accomplish this in the **web interface** of the Konica Minolta 654e printer?

Comment: Are you even sure it is possible to do this through the web interface?  In my experience, the web interface offers a fraction of the features that the printer can actually perform.  It's also possible the reason it's not working the way you think it should is due to the permissions of the user (public) vs (administrator).  Have you tried to authenticate as an Administrator?

Comment: I was logged in as the administrator when I added the subject shown (the screenshot was taken later). It seems foolish to me that they'd provide the ability add a subject (via the web interface), but not the ability to make it default.

Comment: I have two other Konica Minolta printers (models 284e and C364) where the exact steps I've done on the 654e (via the web interface) are successfully changing the email-subject on emailed scanned documents. Perhaps I need to check for firmware updates on the 654e.